# Fetching the max value row wise in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, max, rows

I have a table structure

```
ID  Col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
1    34     23     45     32
2    20     19     67     18
3    40     10     76     86
```

I here want the max value from col_1,col_,col_3,col_4 so my output looks like

```
 ID   Col_1   col_2  col_3  col_4  max
    1    34     23     45     32   45
    2    20     19     67     18   67 
    3    40     10     76     86   86
```

I tried using

```
SELECT ID, MAX(col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4) as max
FROM demo
GROUP BY ID
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the result of the query you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalize the table structure. Try this

```
select ID, max(Col_1) as max_value from
(
select ID, Col_1 from table
union all
select ID, Col_2 from table
union all
select ID, Col_3 from table
union all
select ID, Col_4 from table
) as t group by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use mysql function GREATEST

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, col3, col4, 
GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, col4) AS mx FROM demo
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cbb0/2

Comment: Thanks..it works "Greatest function" came to my rescue.

Answer (score 1):

you may be try this

```
SELECT ID, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, 
GREATEST(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) AS max_value FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

@Thijs to your reference this is the corresponding output I got.

[image]

**query result of first query by @Madhivanan**

[image]

**query result from first of the two solutions provided**